# Trying to update dictionary value

Tags: python

I am just learning programming and have run into a roadblock while trying to make a Zombie Dice game as many have probably seen before. I am trying to add in a points counter that keeps track of each players points throughout the game using a dictionary. In this instance I am trying to add the number of points earned during this round to the player's overall score but when I try to update the "brains" value it keeps giving me this error and I cannot seem to figure out what is going wrong.

```
import random, time

diceTypes = ('green', 'yellow', 'red')
diceSides = ('brains', 'footsteps', 'shotguns')  # Each number represents Brains, Footsteps, and Shotguns
dieRolled = []
result = ''
brainsCounter = 0
shotgunCounter = 0
players = {'Player 1': {'name': 'Lane', 'brains': 0},
           'Player 2': {'name': 'Brian', 'brains': 0},
           'Player 3': {'name': 'Sam', 'brains': 0},
           'Player 4': {'name': 'John', 'brains': 0},
           'Player 5': {'name': 'Jack', 'brains': 0},
           'Player 6': {'name': 'Joseph', 'brains': 0},
           'Player 7': {'name': 'Damian', 'brains': 0},
           'Player 8': {'name': 'Eli', 'brains': 0}}


# Pick three die randomly
def diceDraw():
    dieRolled.extend(random.choices(diceTypes, weights=(33, 34, 33), k=3))
    print('You rolled a ' + str(dieRolled[0]) + ', ' + str(dieRolled[1]) + ', and a ' + str(dieRolled[2]))


# Roll the different die
def redDie():
    result = random.choices(diceSides, weights=(17, 33, 50), k=1)
    feedback(result)


def greenDie():
    result = random.choices(diceSides, weights=(50, 33, 17), k=1)
    feedback(result)


def yellowDie():
    result = random.choices(diceSides, weights=(33, 34, 33), k=1)
    feedback(result)


def feedback(result):
    global brainsCounter, shotgunCounter
    if result[0] == 'brains':
        print('You ate a brain!')
        brainsCounter += 1
    elif result[0] == 'footsteps':
        print('The human got away!')
    else:
        print('You got shot!')
        shotgunCounter += 1


def rollDice(dice):
    for i in dice:
        if i == 'Red':
            redDie()
        elif i == 'Green':
            greenDie()
        else:
            yellowDie()
        time.sleep(1)
        if shotgunCounter == 3:
            break
    if brainsCounter == 1 and shotgunCounter == 1:
        print('You have ' + str(brainsCounter) + ' brain, and have been shot ' + str(shotgunCounter) + ' time.')
    elif brainsCounter != 1 and shotgunCounter == 1:
        print('You have ' + str(brainsCounter) + ' brains, and have been shot ' + str(shotgunCounter) + ' time.')
    elif brainsCounter == 1 and shotgunCounter != 1:
        print('You have ' + str(brainsCounter) + ' brain, and have been shot ' + str(shotgunCounter) + ' times.')
    else:
        print('You have ' + str(brainsCounter) + ' brains, and have been shot ' + str(shotgunCounter) + ' times.')


def turn(player):
    global brainsCounter
    input('Press enter to begin your turn...')
    diceDraw()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        rollDice(dieRolled)
        if shotgunCounter < 3:
            print('Would you like to roll again or stop there? (y/n)')
            answer = input()
            if answer == 'y':
                continue
            elif answer == 'n':
                break
        else:
            print('Your turn is over and you lost those brains!')
            break
    players[[player]['brains']] += brainsCounter
    brainsCounter = 0


# todo determine end of turn and record points for turn

# todo cycle turns between players
# todo determine winner
# todo create catchup round
# todo request number of players and save variable

turn('Player 1')
print(players['Player 1']['brains'])
print(brainsCounter)
```

Comment: “*it keeps giving me this error*” What error...?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: @Prune - actually, the code is runnable in its current form, and can reproduce the problem  You're right on about posting actual and expected results though.  (Is your comment by chance a canned one, and as such, you didn't really consider the codes completeness?  Just a guess knowing that you post these helpful hints a lot).

Comment: The *example* is not complete.  When I run the code, I cannot reproduce OP's problem, because no such problem is specified.  The code is not minimal.  There is no tracing of intermediate results.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
players[[player]['brains']] += brainsCounter
```

I expect that you want:

```
players[player]['brains'] += brainsCounter
```

PS: You really should show the error you're getting in your question, including the full stack trace.